# Python 2.7: Returning a value in a csv file from input

Tags: python-2.7

I've got a csv with:

```
T,8,101
T,10,102
T,5,103
```

and need to search the csv file, in the 3rd column for my input, and if found, return the 2nd column value in that same row (searching "102" would return "10"). I then need to save the result to use in another calculation.  (I am just trying to print the result for now..)  I am new to python (2 weeks) and wanted to get a grasp on reading/writing in csv files.  All the searchable results, didn't give me the answer I needed.  Thanks

Here is my code:

```
name = input("waiting")
import csv
with open('cards.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] == name:
            print(row[1])
```

Comment: Do you really have to use the csv-module? For smaller files I would suggest using Python's standard functions to read files since you do not need to carry out the csv-modules commands. For bigger files I would suggest importing the whole data into a pandas DataFrame. Closing note: I do not suggest not to use the csv-module. However, I think that this task could be carried out without that csv-module. I addition I'd rather prefer pandas against the default csv-module.

Comment: I am going to be doing calculations on a field and then modifying that value into the file, just figured the csv would be easier to do the writing.  I will also be getting an input string that will be comma seperated (or whatever characters I choose) would the csv function still not be better?  However, I did get the code to work, using the 'raw_input()' instead of 'input()'

Comment: If `raw_input` and `input` is a struggle to you, you should first get an idea about which Python version you are using and then take a look at the very basic differences between Python2 and Python3.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment above I would implement a general approach without using the csv-module like this:

```
import io

s = """T,8,101
T,10,102
T,5,103"""

# use io.StringIO to get a file-like object
f = io.StringIO(s)
lines = [tuple(line.split(',')) for line in f.read().splitlines()]

example_look_up = '101'

def find_element(look_up):
    for t in lines:
        if t[2] == look_up:
            return t[1]

result = find_element(example_look_up)
print(result)
```

Please keep in mind, that this is Python3-code. You need to replace `print()` with `print` if using with Python2 and maybe change something related to the `StringIO` which I am using for demonstration purposes here in order to get a file-like object. However, this snippet should give you a basic idea about a possible solution.